# ERB render blank pages on filling select rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, simple-form

I'm trying to render a form using some data from my DB.

Here is my code:

```
<%= form_for(@skinned_build) do |f| %>  
[...]
<%= f.select :bundle_id, BundleId.all.map{ |b| b.name } %>
...
```

This produce a blank page as output, with no error message in the console.
I tried building the map in a method in the controller, same result.
The only way I found to fill my select was using a static method in the model, but I have the feeling I'm missing something.

What did I do wrong ? Where is the best place to build this array ?

Comment: what's the output you're looking for?

Comment: @dax I want a select with all the names contained in the table BundleId. However, instead of generating a partial form, or even an empty select, this code produce a plain blank page

Comment: what's the output of `BundleId.all` in your console?

Comment: `#<BundleId id: 1096, name: "aBundleId", created_at: "2013-11-06 08:32:49", updated_at: "2013-11-06 08:32:49">, #<BundleId id: 1097, name: "anOtherOne", created_at: "2013-11-06 08:32:49", updated_at: "2013-11-06 08:32:49">, [...]`

Comment: @dax restarting rails to launch the console solved my problem. Without your comment, I might be still searching the answer for some time :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting rails solved the problem.